# Why Catch statment not working React Js (Firebase Auth)?

Tags: reactjs, async-await, firebase-authentication

```js
const submitHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setErr("");
    try {
      await signUp(email, password, firstName, lastName);
      err.length === 0 &&
        setTimeout(() => {
          navigate("/");
        }, [2000]);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
      setErr(error.message);
    }
  };
```

When I submit the form with the existing email I got the error but the **Catch** statement not show the **error.message** or set the **state**

Getting this normal **error** not the message

```
Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/email-already-in-use).
    at createErrorInternal (assert.ts:122:1)
    at _createError (assert.ts:83:1)
    at _makeTaggedError (index.ts:261:1)
    at _performFetchWithErrorHandling (index.ts:161:1)
    at async _performSignInRequest (index.ts:191:1)
    at async createUserWithEmailAndPassword (email_and_password.ts:23
```

Comment: try only console.log(error)...and don't do the timeout thing. just navigate directly on success

Comment: Still have the same issue

Comment: Only console.log(error) should give something, if error is happening. And you are not needed to catch error in another err variable, just try catch would solve the issue

Comment: I am getting normal error i need to catch the msg to set it as state to handle errors and render different messages, I updated the question added the error I'm getting

Comment: Try the answer.

Comment: First of all, are you sure this `signUp` function throws in your `submitHandler` function? Because it looks like this error is being handled somewhere else.. In order to `catch` the error, first you need to throw it. So, for example, if there's a `try catch` inside the `signUp` fn, you need to `throw` the error AGAIN in order to `catch` it in the `submitHandler` fn.

Comment: Glad to help. I'll post my answer in the topic, please mark as resolved. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, are you sure this `signUp` function throws an error?

Because it looks like this error is being handled somewhere else.. In order to catch the error, first you need to throw it.

So, for example, if there's a `try catch` inside `signUp`, you need to `throw` the error AGAIN in order to `catch` it in `submitHandler`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue

> assert.ts:136 Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/email-already-in-use).

I did try to alert a message in catch block but code in catch block seem like not working.
Regards,
Thang

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).